# B. Ordenando de forma ascendente y descendente

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

tengo un inconveniente, implemente un algoritmo de ordenamiento rápido (QuickSort), para poder resolver el siguiente problema:

**Descripción**

Dado un arreglo de ***N*** enteros, escribe un programa que procese una lista de ***M*** instrucciones a ejecutar secuencialmente, las cuales pueden ser de los siguientes tipos:

1. **"<"**: Ordenar el arreglo de menor a mayor.
2. **">"**: Ordenar el arreglo de mayor a menor.
3. I ***K***: Imprimir el valor actual del ***K***-ésimo elemento del arreglo.

**Entrada**

Un entero ***N*** seguido de los ***N*** enteros del arreglo. Posteriormente, un entero ***M*** seguido de las ***M*** instrucciones. Puedes suponer que ***1≤N≤10^5***, que ***1≤M≤10^6***, que ***0≤K<N*** y que la primera instrucción será ya sea < o >.

***Salida***

Para cada instrucción del tipo I ***K***, el valor actual del ***K***-ésimo elemento del arreglo.

Mi código realizado es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Función para intercambiar dos elementos en un vector
void swap(vector<int>& arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

// Función para dividir el arreglo y colocar el pivote en su posición correcta
int partition(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    int pivot = arr[high]; // seleccionamos el último elemento como pivote
    int i = low - 1; // índice del elemento más pequeño

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        // Si el elemento actual es menor o igual que el pivote
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++; // incrementamos el índice del elemento más pequeño
            swap(arr, i, j); // intercambiamos arr[i] y arr[j]
        }
    }
    swap(arr, i + 1, high); // colocamos el pivote en su posición correcta
    return i + 1; // retornamos la posición del pivote
}

// Función recursiva para ordenar el arreglo usando QuickSort
void quickSort(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        // obtenemos la posición del pivote
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // ordenamos los subarreglos antes y después del pivote
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    // leer los elementos del arreglo
    vector<int> arr(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // ordenar el arreglo inicial
    quickSort(arr, 0, N - 1);

    // procesar las instrucciones
    int M;
    cin >> M;

    char instruction;
    int K;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        cin >> instruction;
        if (instruction == '<') {
            quickSort(arr, 0, N - 1); // ordenar de menor a mayor
        } else if (instruction == '>') {
            reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end()); // ordenar de mayor a menor
        } else {
            cin >> K; // obtener el índice K
            cout << arr[K] << endl; // imprimir el valor del K-ésimo elemento
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión es la siguiente, al momento de subirlo a la plataforma me lo marca como "Tiempo límite excedido" (TLE), ¿puede que este fallando en la forma que se están manejando las instrucciones de ordenamiento en cada iteración del ciclo?
¿Cómo podría optimizarlo?
Saludos.

Comment: Ordena el arreglo una sola vez (en la primera aparición de la instrucción < o >), después simplemente indexa adecuadamente, no necesitas ni invertirlo ni reordenarlo, solo calcular el índice correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El array no cambia a lo largo de toda la ejecución. Esto significa que una vez que lo ordenes no tienes que volver a tocarlo, cuando te pida el valor k-ésimo:

- Si la última instrucción de ordenación ha sido "<" simplemente indizar sobre el array con `k`.
- Si la última instrucción de ordenamiento ha sido ">" significa que debes indizar en orden inverso, no inviertas el array, basta con calcular el indice correcto (`N - 1 - k`).

Basta con modificar un poco el ciclo encargado de procesar las instrucciones, algo así:

```
bool left_to_right = true;

if (M <= 1) {
    return 0;
}

// ordenar el arreglo inicial
quickSort(arr, 0, N - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    cin >> instruction;
    if (instruction == '<') {
        left_to_right = true;
    } else if (instruction == '>') {
        left_to_right = false;    
    } else {
        cin >> K; // obtener el índice K
        if (left_to_right) {
            cout << arr[K] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << arr[N - 1 - K] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Dado que `M` puede ser 1 y que la primera instrucción es siempre "<" o ">", ni siquiera es necesario ordenar el array en este caso. También puede darse el caso de que habiendo más de 1 instrucción, todas ellas sean de ordenación, en cuyo caso tampoco tendrías que ordenarlo. Si esto resulta un problema bastaría con agregar otra bandera que indique si el array está ordenado y ordenarlo solo cuando pida el primer k-ésimo número.